# why this function automatic execute when app start

Tags: objective-c, ios, llvm

This is my code.

```
#import "States.h" 

@interface States ()
+ (NSString *)statesFilePath;
@end

static NSMutableDictionary *states = nil;

@implementation States
+ (NSString *)statesFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *statesFilePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:gStatesFile];
    return statesFilePath;
}

+ (void)load
{   
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [states release];
    NSString *filePath = [[States statesFilePath] retain];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        states = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    } else {
        states = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"ID"] retain];
    }
    [filePath release];
    [pool release];
}
```

I know store states in a static variant wasn't a good idea.

**But my question is: why load() automatic executed every time when the app starts?**

Cause the states is an unassigned static variant, the complier **automaticly** find a method to init it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load function is called whenever a static class is added to the runtime, so whats happening to you is normal behavior, if you want a function to not be called, name it something else

from [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Invoked whenever a class or category is added to the Objective-C
>   runtime; implement this method to perform class-specific behavior upon
>   loading.

Comment: Thanks, this is one of my guesses.